# Can't find variable: Component in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm building a simple app with react native using among other things Expo. After an update of react, expo, react-native from a previous version, I get an error I cannot seem to get rid of (see picture). I have looked in index.js, MainNavigator.js, LoginNavigator.js to ensure that I have `import React, {Component } from 'react';` in the preamble, but the problem persists. Can anyone guide me in a direction to help solve this problem?

[image]

Also tried:

- Running `exp install:ios` to make sure that I have the latest version on the simulator
- Several of the solutions mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d), e.g. `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache` and `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start --reset-cache`
- Re-installing expo with `npm install exp --global`
- Following the [upgrade guide](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v25-0-0-is-now-available-714d10a8c3f7) at from Expo for SDK v25.0.0, i.e. changing `app.json` `package.json`, deleting `node_modules` and then running `exp start -c`.
- Running `react-native link`.
- Using `import React from 'react';`and then `... extends React.Component`
- Manually installing all packages except `react-native`, `expo` and `react` again using ´npm install [package] --save`

Excerpt from package.json:
[image: Versions:]

Comment: Try running packager in terminal ‘npm run — —reset-cache’ and then ‘react-native run-ios’. I think the paths have changes in update but the packager is using cached paths.

Comment: Tried running 'npm run --reset-cache' and then 'exp start' and 'exp ios' (I use expo), but the problem unfortunately persists...

Comment: I had such an issue a while ago.... For me I did not have all libraries properly linked in XCode. Try running `react-native link` or simply remove external libraries from the code 1 by 1 to  see what is causing this. Good luck!

Comment: When updating did you follow the upgrading guide and do it one version at a time? https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v25-0-0-is-now-available-714d10a8c3f7

Comment: Does the same happen if you import and use Component like this:
`import React from 'react';`
`class App extends React.Component`

???

Comment: @spooky thanks for the suggestion - tried, but without luck...

Comment: @MattAft Initially, not certain that I followed exactly this procedure, but did it again with the instructions at the link, but I still get the error when eventually doing `exp start -c´

Comment: @flaky Yes, tried that as well..

Comment: @MattAft apologies, didn't understand it initially, but went back and upgraded one version at a time and now it worked. If you'll write an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @dahved awesome, glad it worked. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When upgrading expo versions, make sure you follow their upgrading guide and do it one version at a time: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v25-0-0-is-now-available-714d10a8c3f7

Answer (score 14):

My solution was changing this line as:
From

```
import React from 'react';
```

To

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this issue in my project. First add react-native to your packages.

```
yarn add react-native
```

Then changing below line:

**OLD**

```
import React from 'react';
```

**NEW**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

npm start -- --reset-cache

and Invailidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before, after searching all thorough the codebase, finally, I found it where I couldn't believe it'll be `App.js` file. So if you've tried restarting your bundler and running `npm start --reset-cache` or `yarn start --reset-cache`, and the issue still persist, check all your files and components you worked on, you imported `React` without importing `Component`, for instance:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Answer (score -2):

see that  if you are use classes in react-native then you should add {component} from react as given below.

import {component} from React;

Comment: This question was posted (and answered) two and a half years ago.